# angular change class by id

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have collection in angular. the collection looks like:

```
$scope.collection = [{id:'a1', title:'title 1'}, {id:'a2', title:'title 2'}];
<span ng-repeat="c in collection" id="{{c.id}}">{{c.title}}</span>
```

it is then itterate using `ngRepeat` in a `span` tag. in other line i have buttons that have custom property, let say `data-span-id`, like so:

```
<button type="button" data-span-id="a1">
<button type="button" data-span-id="a2">
```

when that buttons clicked, i want to change the class of the `span` that have `id` equal to `data-span-id` property. in jQuery

```
$('#'+$(this).data('span-id')).addClass('someclass');
```

how to this in angular? PS: spans and buttons is scallable.

Comment: could you show me some code ? is your span child of your ng repeat ?

Comment: I think that your solution is very "jQuery-oriented", and maybe you should think different in AngularJS to implement what you have in mind. In my view, this framework is not designed to implement your program like this.

Comment: you can always use `ng-class="yourClass(id)"` where yourClass() is a function in the scope wich returns the class for your id.

Comment: @bviale: haha yeah, very jquery-oriented.. i am new to angular

Comment: You do have a typo, `idL: 'a2'` edit: did ;)

Comment: Checkout ng-class, you will use that directive to solve this problem

Comment: @DarielPratama checkout James Gaunt solution, way more AngularJS-oriented :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to answer without seeing more of your code, but something along these lines is how I'd do it....

```
<button ng-repeat="item in collection" ng-click="selected = item.id">{{ item.title }}</button>

<span ng-repeat="item in collection"  ng-class="{ 'someClass': selected == item.id }">{{ item.title }}</span>
```

So clicking a button sets a variable in the scope to the id you want, and then your span checks for that variable to set a class.